# String to WritableKeyPath

Tags: swift, swift4

How do I convert a `String` to a `WritableKeyPath`?

Something like:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let x: Bool
}

let string = "x"

let myStruct = MyStruct(x: false)
let x = myStruct[keyPath: keyPathFromString(string)!]
```

Comment: Can you give some more context here? It isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve. Does the string you are trying to convert have a specific format, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: @ØyvindHauge I edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.  The reason behind this is that Swift is doing its best to try to give us "dynamic-like" features in the language, while still providing compile-time checking for key paths.  If they were to allow conversion of a String to a key path, then the key path would be determined at runtime instead of compile time.

You asked a perfectly valid question, so I recommend asking a new question that is a more specific use case in what you are trying to achieve.  Even though key paths are limited to compile time, they are still a powerful language feature and there may be a way to do what you want using them or another Swift 4 feature such as the new Codable protocol.